# Pulling a specific event's title and startDate from Event Kit iPhone iOS

Tags: iphone, ios4, eventkit

I have looked over apple's same code and haven't figured it out.

I am trying to pull a single event's title and startDate from Event Kit in iOS 4.0 or later.

I have taken Apple's EKDemo sample code and tried modifying the didSelect method, but the app SIGBART out every time I modified it. any ideas?

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
           // Upon selecting an event, create an EKEventViewController to display the event.
          self.detailViewController = [[EKEventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];           
         detailViewController.event = [self.eventsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Allow event editing.
       detailViewController.allowsEditing = YES;

       //   Push detailViewController onto the navigation controller stack
        //  If the underlying event gets deleted, detailViewController will remove itself from
          //    the stack and clear its event property.
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    }
```